# Android Studio 2.3.1 Component Tree and Palette missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated Android Studio to 2.3.1. Now, when I´m trying to edit a layout through graphic mode, component tree and Palette are not visible anywhere. I have searched too much in Google and I have could not found something that solve the problem. Thanks for your time and attention. Excuse my posible poor english.

Comment: Have you tried to `Restore default layout` from window menu, normally you can use the shortcut `shift+f12` ?

Comment: Thank you man!!. You saved my life.:D

Comment: You're  Welcome  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Restore default layout` from window menu, normally you can use the shortcut `shift+f12`

Comment: Thanks my friend. :D